# How to perform breadth first search using python3 pandas dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, breadth-first-search

A single row in the dataframe looks like the following:

```
source                                                                           Bubble Sort
target                                        Sorting Algorithms Visualization : Bubble Sort
edge      https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms-visualization-bubble-sort/?ref=rp
```

The columns are source, target and edge.
Given two nodes src and dest. I need to perform BFS and get all the edges in the path.
For example from source **Bubble Sort** to target **Sorting Algorithms Visualization : Bubble Sort**.
It should output :

```
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms-visualization-bubble-sort/?ref=rp.
```

I am new to python and python dataframes and need a little help figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this, if I understood the question correctly:

```
print(df[(df['source'] == 'Bubble Sort') & (df['target'] == 'Sorting Algorithms Visualization : Bubble Sort')]['edge'])

0    https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorith...
```

Comment: Does it give the weight if there is an edge between source or target, or it can give a list of edges when a path exists between two nodes?

Comment: If the dataframe has those 3 columns you mentioned, the above query will give all the edges that satisfy the condition -  source = 'Bubble Sort' and target = 'Sorting Algorithms Visualization : Bubble Sort'

Comment: If a row is ['a','b','1'] and another is ['b','c',2]. If i need a pth between 'a' to 'c'. It should print 1,2

Comment: So you're saying b is a target in the first but source in the second row?

Comment: Yes, and I require path.